# Can't find php_ldap.dll for PHP 5.3.3 on Windows?

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to install PHP with LDAP support on Windows, but I can't seem to find the proper php_ldap.dll file anywhere. I've looked in both the installer and the zip file with no luck.

Does anyone know where I can get this file?

Answer (score 2):

I just downloaded the PHP 5.3.3 VC9 Thread-safe zip for windows. It does indeed have php_ldap.dll in the ext/ directory, as it always has been. I suggest you download a fresh copy from the [official download site](http://windows.php.net/download/) and try again.

**Edit:** I just checked the VC6 Thread-safe binaries (for Apache 1 & 2) and it is indeed missing from that one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after looking for awhile, as far as I can tell, PHP 5.3.3 doesn't have the LDAP dll available for it. I was able to downgrade to 5.3.1 to get LDAP back. Hope this helps someone in the future.